# Qual melhor método de utilizar o SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, token, armazenamento

Tenho um aplicativo com uma webview na qual retorna um Token quando o usuário faz o login. Preciso salvar as informações do usuário para realizar o auto-login na próxima vez que ele entrar, pretendo fazer isso utilizando o CheckBox. Após pesquisar bastante, vi que o melhor a fazer é armazenar o Token, e não o usuário e senha, porém qual a melhor forma de fazer isto? Desde já agradecido!

Comment: A sua dúvida é não saber usar o SharedPreferences para gravar o Token? Ou sabe usar mas o problema é usá-lo nesse contexto?

Comment: Sei usar, vi uns exemplos gravando user e pass e consegui reproduzir, mas não consegui encaixar no contexto do Token, e não encontrei muitos exemplos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor maneira de armazenar o seu `Token` é quando o usuário estiver conectado com sucesso, ou seja, quando o `Token` já tiver sido criado com sucesso. Depois disso, basta salvar o `Token`.

Por exemplo, o usuário se conectou na `LoginActivity` e foi redirecionado para a `HomeActivity`, então...

> Home Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences mPref = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle cicle) {
        super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home.xml); // Layout

        // SharedPreferences
        mPref = getSharedPreferences("tokenId", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        mPref.edit().putInt("tokenId", "9102887").apply();
    }
}
```

> Login Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences mPref = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle cicle) {
        super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home.xml); // Layout

        // SharedPreferences
        mPref = getSharedPreferences("tokenId", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        // Se o token não for encontrado, o valor será 0
        int token = mPref.getInt("tokenId", 0);

        // Envia um pedido de token pro servidor
        // recebe o token e compara com o token salvo
        // se forem semelhantes, entra na conta direto
        int tokenServer = webS.getToken(deviceId, user, pass);

        if(token == tokenServer) // sucesso
    }
}
```

Você não precisa **necessariamente** salvar o `Token` como `Int`. Foi apenas um exemplo, acredito que o recomendado para seu caso seja uma `String` mesmo. E não muda muita coisa, apenas de `putInt` para `putString`. Veja na **documentação**.

**Fonte**: [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Consegui entender o contexto, vou tentar reproduzir, valeu!